# Word VBA - Issue with Table Merging

Tags: windows, vba, merge, ms-word, ms-office

I have a document with several tables with rows that require merging, however one specific table is causing issues failing on the first row of the merge while the rest have no issues.

Here is the code for the merge, it finds a unique string only contained within that one table to identify the table and then attempts to merge it.

```
'Merge Table
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Unique String"
    .Execute
End With

'If this selection is in the table

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        'First row of merges
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=1).Merge _ 'Here is where the merge throws an error "The requested member of the collection does not exist"
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=3).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=3)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=4).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=4)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=5).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=5)

        'Second row of merges
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=3).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=3)
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=4).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=4)
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=5).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=5)

        'More merges here
    End With
End If
```

And table format is the following (sample provided) Pre Merge:

[image]

Here is how I would like them to be after the merge (sample provided) End table result:

[image]

As I had mentioned, the code for this merge works with every other table, however not this one. Any ideas why?

**Update**

The code is working on its own but when 2 merges for 2 separate tables are in the same macro, the combined code runs but only seems to merge one table and skips the next.

```
 With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Unique String 1"
    .Execute
End With

'If this selection is in the Table

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=6, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=7, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=8, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=10, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=12, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=15, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=16, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=18, Column:=1)
    End With
End If

    'Merge Table
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Unique String 2"
    .Execute
End With

'If this selection is in the table

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        'First row of merges
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=1).Merge _ 'Here is where the merge throws an error "The requested member of the collection does not exist"
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=3).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=3)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=4).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=4)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=5).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=5)

        'Second row of merges
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=1).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=1)
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=3).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=3)
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=4).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=4)
        .Cell(Row:=4, Column:=5).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=5, Column:=5)

        'More merges here
    End With
End If
```

Comment: If you comment out the line that errors, do the rest run through OK?

Comment: The error just seems to move to the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your problem description and table depictions it appears you could use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call TblProcessor("Unique String 1")
Call TblProcessor("Unique String 2")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub TblProcessor(StrFnd As String)
Dim c As Long, r As Long, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = StrFnd
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      With .Tables(1)
        For i = .Range.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          With .Range.Cells(i)
            r = .RowIndex: c = .ColumnIndex
          End With
          If r < 3 Then Exit For
          If Split(.Cell(r, c).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "" Then
            .Cell(r - 1, c).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(r, c)
          End If
        Next
      End With
      .End = .Tables(1).Range.End
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So this solution worked when run on its own (upvoted), but so did my problem code. When they are implemented with a macro that has 2 merges (merge1 and merge2 for ex) then your solution (merge2) does not merge the table but the other merge (merge1) works. On the contrary the opposite happens when using my code in the OP, in that the other merge is the one not occuring but mine does. I've updated the OP to explain it more clearly.

Comment: All that requires is a trivial change to the appraoch, really. See my updated code.